# fetch detail from mysql using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Kindly help me with the ajax / jQuery to fetch all the objects of a array.

I am using the following code and it doesn't work

```js
$(window).on("load", GetAllProperties);

function GetAllProperties() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'userdetailfetch.php', //the script to call to get data                
    dataType: 'json', //data format      
    success: function(data) //on recieve of reply
    {
      $('#ph').html(data[0]);
      $('#email').html(data[1]);
      $('#name').html(data[2]);
      $('#fname').html(data[3]);
      $('#date').html(data[4]);
      $('#course').html(data[5]);
      $('#branch').html(data[6]);
      $('#sem').html(data[7]);
      $('#roll').html(data[8]);
    }
  });
}
```

**fetchuserdetail.php**

```
<?php
$cnx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "loginerp");
$result = mysqli_query($cnx, "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE id='" . $_SESSION['sessuser'] . "'");
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] =$row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I want to display all the details when the page loads .

Thanks for your help.

Comment: add `type:'POST'` in `$.ajax({  })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start session in fetchuserdetail.php file
session_start();

Correct the page name 
url: 'fetchuserdetail.php',